# SSL connection in Flash socket?

Tags: flash, security, sockets, ssl

Is it possible to establish an SSL connection from a Socket in Flash?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know directly from flash player, client side, browser, you can't.

If you ask generally about flash:

[This part of the reference](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/SecureSocket.html) describes a subclass of the Socket class, called SecureSocket, what seems to do the job, but only in AIR 2.

Maybe it fits your needs. Otherwise you might use some server-side code, connect the flash and make the requests through the server-side.